# Jquery add class by index skipping every 13th row

Tags: jquery

I am using dataTables to break a table up with a fixed column and header. It is a large tabled populated with php.

I have the following jquery code

```
$(document).on({
mouseenter: function () {
    trIndex = $(this).index()+1;
    console.log(trIndex);
    $("table.dataTable").each(function() {
        $(this).find("tr:eq("+trIndex+")").addClass("hover")
    });
},
mouseleave: function () {
    trIndex = $(this).index()+1;
    $("table.dataTable").each(function(index) {
        $(this).find("tr:eq("+trIndex+")").removeClass("hover")
    });
}
}, ".dataTables_wrapper tr");
```

Since the fixed column is actually broken up into 2 tables by dataTables, I am trying to fetch the index of the row I am hovering over and then apply the class hover to the row with that index in the fixed column and in the main body of the table.

I have looked in chromes inspector and each row's index is incrementing by 1 as expected. The row in the fixed column is adding the class hover as expected, however in the main body the first row has the hover class added when hovering, but then row 14 adds the class hover to the second row, row 27 adds the hover class to the 3rd row, etc. All the rows in between do not add the hover class to any row in the main body.

What could be causing this strange result? 
As you can see in the code I have console logged the index of each row when I hover and it produced the correct index number.

Thanks

Comment: can you send more code?

Comment: Showing your HTML would help.

Comment: I tried test your code but dont see any problems - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4pNp/)

Comment: "fixed column" ... "header" ... "main body". My head is spinning. I would need a diagram.